# Comparing Date with Date and where Status value not equal 23 or 25

Tags: powershell, operators

I am comparing 2 dates and statuscode. If 2 dates are same and status codes are not 23 or status code are not 25 then give me the records. but the following is not working.

```
elseif(((get-date $Date1).Date -eq (get-date $Date2).Date) -And ($status -ne "23" -Or $status -ne "25"))
                    {
                        write-host $accountName -foregroundcolor "yellow"   
}
```

Comment: Any chance there's leading or trailing whitespace in the $status value?

Comment: I can do a trim before evaluating them. good catch

Comment: Just tried $status.trim() before evaluating but it did not work.  any other ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is correct:

```
($status -ne "23" -Or $status -ne "25")
```

should it not be an -And operator, for example:

```
($status -ne "23" -And $status -ne "25")
```

Explanation:

When $status = "23", then $status -ne "23" IS FALSE but $status -ne "25" IS TRUE
therefore $status -ne "23" -Or $status -ne "25" simplifies to $false -Or $true, which simplifies to $true

The explanation is the same for $status = "25".

When $status is something different to "23" and "25" then $status -ne "23" IS TRUE and $status -ne "25" IS TRUE therefore ($status -ne "23" -Or $status -ne "25") simplifies to ($true -Or $true) which simplifies to $true

Given the cases above this means that ($status -ne "23" -Or $status -ne "25") IS ALWAYS TRUE regardless of the input

Comment: I think you are right. You could do it like this too `$status -notin ("23", "25")`. (That might need PowerShell 3.) I don't get why the poster doesn't just plug in some values to the expression and test it. That would have to be more efficient that posting to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you `get-date $Date1` I assume you have a date value stored in $Date1 and $Date2 I would just compare it like this:

```
elseif(($Date1 -eq $Date2) -And ($status -ne "23" -Or $status -ne "25"))
                    {
                        write-host $accountName -foregroundcolor "yellow"   
}
```

If you dont have a date value in $Date1 and $Date2 I would calculate those first and store them then do your elseif.

To add to this if your values in $Date1 and $Date2 are strings and you want to convert them to a date time you can do `[datetime]$Date1`

Comment: The time with Date1 and Date2 are different but date is same. so thats why I am using get-date method to ignore time part from each date variable.

Comment: @ShawnTorres, you still don't need the Get-Date. You can compare them like this: `$Date1.Date -eq $Date2.Date`